# how can validate psr-jwt token on every api call

Tags: php, slim, slim-3, slim-4

I am using https://github.com/RobDWaller/psr-jwt library in my slim4 application

I want to validate the token before the API call. if the token is valid, API should call else an error should prompt. Below is my code

```
//routes.php
$app->group('/myapp/login', function (Group $group) {
        $group->post('', LoginProcess::class);
    });

$app->group('/myapp/register', function (Group $group) {
        $group->post('', RegisterProcess::class);
    });
$app->group('/,myapp', function (Group $group) {
        $group->get('/list', ListUser::class);
    });

//middlware.php
<?php
use App\Application\Middleware\AuthMiddleware;
use Slim\App;
return function (App $app) {
$app->add(\PsrJwt\Factory\JwtMiddleware::html('Secret123!456$', 'jwt', 'Authorisation Failed'));
};
```

Is it validate the token itself. are any other methods exist?
my question is:

1. How to write custom errors?
2. How to exclude middleware to log in, register apis before authenticated & after authenticated.

   I am new to the slim framework. please help me.

Comment: *How to write custom errors?* - what sort of thing are you after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To invoke a middleware on routing level you can add that middleware to a specific route and/or a routing group.

Slim 4 example:

```php
use Slim\Routing\RouteCollectorProxy;
use PsrJwt\Factory\JwtMiddleware;
// ...

$app->group('/myapp', function (RouteCollectorProxy $group) {
    $group->post('/login', LoginProcess::class);
    $group->post('/register', RegisterProcess::class);
    $group->get('/list', RegisterProcess::class);

})->add(JwtMiddleware::html('Secret123!456$', 'jwt', 'Authorisation Failed'));
```